Is it legal for employer to make getting paid for work contingent on completion of certain tasks?
I sometimes do part time work where I'm periodically required to provide proof of residency documents for tax reasons. Management said I need to do this to get paid, but someone else advised they can't legally do this. Which is true? Can payment be contingent on things such as clocking in and out, completing on boarding paper work and training, or submitting a report? I'm particularly interested in Canada, but also other countries too.

TD1 is an Obligation under tax law
Tax law requires employers to provide quite some information to the tax authorities. By law, the company has to have at least SIN and TD1. Without having the proper taxation information required and retaining the taxes, the company does violate tax laws in paying you as an employee. Not filling in TD1 in time is costly for the employee:

Penalties
If the individual does not provide you with the TD1 form when required, they are liable to a penalty of $25 for each day the form is late. The minimum penalty is $100, and increases by $25 per day to a maximum of $2,500.

Form TD-1 requires Name, SIN and address.
There's labor law obligations for employees
For Federal Work, Part II of the Canada Labor Code has several obligations to employees, mostly relating to health and safety. Among them is fulfilling training regarding those rules and reporting.
In British Columbia, very similar obligations are put forth by the provincial laws as part of the Worker's compensation Act (section 22)
Employment can be contingent on fulfilling obligations
An employment contract can make further employment past the training or probation period hinge on completing training during it.
Work rendered is to be paid
Under the various worker rights acts, work rendered is to be paid. Often, a multitude of laws interact here: For example, above mentioned BC Worker's Compensation Act Section 47(2) bans reduction in pay as a punishment against a worker, and BC's Employment Standards Act Section 20-28 dictates that and how wages are to be paid, what is deductible and what not.
As a general rule of thumb: Any work rendered - that includes time in training or during the probationary period - is to be paid to the extent that the work or time was rendered.

I think this question could be improved by distinguishing between "make getting paid for work" [already performed] and granting employment/entering employment contract/requiring fulfilment of documentary requirements of a contract which is the question you are answering and I am sure the real world useful answer.

Giving you a job may depend on the right paperwork. As soon as you actually work, if they have been violating any rules then that is done. They still have to pay you. Plus there are no “tax reasons”, taxes would be the same whether you are working legally or illegally.

"Giving you a job may depend on the right paperwork". Is there a certain point where this no longer is a valid argument? For example they probably can't withhold pay for not having completed the anti-bullying videos that they say is a required part of the on boarding process.

You worked, they have to pay. If you didn’t complete these videos and therefore shouldn’t have worked, but were told to work, or you worked and nobody stopped you, they need to pay.

@StumpTheCheff2 If you don't fulfill the job requirements, they can simply fire you. They'll have to pay you for any work you did before getting fired, though.
